# How to use observeEvent with a checkbox event Shiny

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

How do I trigger an action (in this case updateSelectInput) with observeEvent based on a TRUE/FALSE checkbox event?

For example I would like to update result when test is TRUE:

```
library(shiny)
ui<-fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("test","Test",value=FALSE),
  selectInput("result","Result",choices=c("1","2","3"),selected="1")
)

server<-function(input, output){
  observeEvent(input$test{
    updateSelectInput(session,"result",choices=c("1","2","3","4","5"),selected="1")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below:

```
library(shiny)
ui<-fluidPage(
    checkboxInput("test","Test",value=FALSE),
    selectInput("result","Result",choices=c("1","2","3"),selected="1")
)

server<-function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$test,{
        updateSelectInput(session,"result",choices=c("1","2","3","4","5"),selected="1")
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

I added `session` to the server `function()`, a comma after `input$test`, and `ignoreInit = TRUE`.

**Update**

```
library(shiny)
ui<-fluidPage(
    checkboxInput("test","Test",value=FALSE),
    selectInput("result","Result",choices=c("1","2","3"),selected="1")
)

server<-function(input, output, session){
    observeEvent(input$test,{
        updateSelectInput(session,"result",choices=if(input$test == FALSE){c("1","2","3")}else{c("1","2","3","4","5")},selected="1")

    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}


shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: Right, I forget session. It works, but as soon as checkbox return FALSE, it does not reupdate selectInput to the original state. Can you please tell me easily what ignoreInit does?

Comment: You haven't created an updateSelectInput for the FALSE case. I'll update my solution above. ignoreInit just ignores the fist event observed in this case input$test = FALSE that you set in the ui

Comment: See update above. You could leave out ignoreInit = TRUE but it's slightly more efficient in this case

Comment: Last question: what about once and ignoreNull?

Comment: Documentation at that link:
ignoreNULL Whether the action should be triggered (or value calculated, in the case of eventReactive) when the input is NULL. See Details.
ignoreInit If TRUE, then, when this observeEvent is first created/initialized, ignore the handlerExpr (the second argument), whether it is otherwise supposed to run or not. The default is FALSE. See Details.
once Whether this observeEvent should be immediately destroyed after the first time that the code in handlerExpr is run. This pattern is useful when you want to subscribe to a event that should only happen once.

Comment: Basically ignoreInit = TRUE would ignore the first occurrence (default is FALSE). ignoreNULL = TRUE ignores the case where the observed event - in this case input$test is NULL. Doesn't happen in your example as it can only be TRUE or FALSE. once = TRUE means the observeEvent runs once and then "dies" and doesn't get triggered again.